# Can't conver complex to float where is no complex numbers

Tags: python, function, numpy, math, complex-numbers

"Can't conver complex to float" error refers to `M[i] = odwr_funk_PM(kat_PM[i])`. There is no any complex numbery in `kat_PM` array.

```py
def odwr_funk_PM(kat_PM): 
    kat_PM= math.radians(kat_PM)
    kat_PM_0= 0.5*math.pi*(math.sqrt(6)-1)
    y= (kat_PM/kat_PM_0)**(2/3)
    liczba_Macha= (1+(1.3604)*y+(0.0962)*y**2+(-0.5127)*y**3)/(1+(-0.6722)*y+(-0.3278)*y**2)
    return liczba_Macha

kat_PM[i] = (kat_theta[i-n+ g]+ kat_PM[i-n+ g]-kat_theta[i-1]+ kat_PM[i-1]+ ((1/(np.sqrt((M[i-n+ g]**2)-1)-mp.cot(math.radians(kat_theta[i-n+ g]))))*((y[i]-y[i-n+ g])/y[i-n+ g]))+ ((1/(np.sqrt((M[i-1]**2)-1)-mp.cot(math.radians(kat_theta[i-1]))))*((y[i]-y[i-1])/y[i-1])))/2

M[i] = odwr_funk_PM(kat_PM[i])
```

Here is the [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/macaronipasta/Python/master/kat_PM) to my github with the values of kat_PM array.

I tried to use `1/np.tan` instead `mp.cot`, but the result is the same.

How to avoid this error or force array to "convert" numbers from complex to float?

Comment: I'm guessing you're square rooting something that's negative in the middle of that massive arithmetic expression? Try breaking it up a bit, and see where the complex number is being introduced.

Comment: Also be aware that something that should be zero could, by rounding errors, be just below zero, giving an almost zero complex value when doing the square root.

Comment: It's likely the `**(2/3)` on a negative value that's giving a complex result, rather than the square root (which should give a `nan` instead). But we're missing context here (what's `mp`? what's `kat_theta`?), so it's difficult to tell.

Answer (score 2):

You do in fact have a negative value in your data:
 -101.54242018
Fix this, and your complex values should disappear.